# Parse.com identify if the user is an anonymous user when calling cloud code

Tags: javascript, parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to secure my app build on parse.com. 
I am using cloud code to save sove objects and ideally, I would allow registered user to do things that anonymous ones don't.
Is there a way that I can detect if the user who is calling cloud code is a registered user or an anonymous user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the documentation here. I think `authenticated()` is what you need. https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html

Comment: Thanks Jimi, this seems to be was I was looking for.

Comment: The link now is https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `authenticated()` method of the `Parse.User()` class. See https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html